# Function works using script tags in html but not in knockout js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Hi I have a knockout js file called register.js which has this function

```
self.checkValidation = function(){
           $('#register_form').validate(function(valid, elem) {
            var value = valid;
            if(value){
                alert(value);
            }else{
                alert(value);
            }
            });
 }
```

And the same one in the html page but under script tags.

```
<script>
    $('#openUpTwoStepAuth').click(function(){
    $('#register_form').validate(function(valid, elem) {
    var value = valid;
    if(value){
        alert(value);
    }else{
        alert(value);
        // call the self.checkValidation here if other options fails.
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And here is the button that calls both the functions

```
<button data-bind="enable: AgreedtoTerm, click : checkValidation " type="submit" id="openUpTwoStepAuth" class="btn registerbtn">
                <?php echo lang("register_continue_btn"); ?>
            </button>
```

For some reason the function works perfectly from the html script tags, and also alerts the values, but when I call the same function in the `self.checkValidation` it does not work, so what I want to do is either make the self.checkValidation work, and if it does not work, some how call the `self.checkValidation` from the script tags, so I can call some other function, which is the last resort.

I am using a form, to check validations, of input fields, and the script tag works properly.

Comment: Because you are just adding event `$('#register_form').validate(` inside `checkValidation`.

Comment: @Rajesh how can I fix it then?

Comment: You just have to put logic in that function. To be specific, codde of `$('#register_form').validate` in `checkValidation`

Comment: @Rajesh sorry I am pretty new to this, so I am not sure what you mean by code of `$('#register_form').validate`

Comment: @Rajesh the .validate is coming from a jqueryformvalidator.js file which is a third party js file.